# How to save state pagination with list.js after refresh?

Tags: listjs

Iam using List.js to create pagination. How to saving state pagination number after refresh. if in page number 3, then refresh, page number stil in page 3.
http://listjs.com

Answer (score 1):

In listPagination.js you have

```
e.bind(a,"click",function(){
}
```

Inside this function at the beginning you have to write

```
e.bind(a,"click",function(){
    $(this).find('a').html()
}
```

With this, you have the page active, after you save this where you want, and apply the class active in this page !

Hope this can help you :)